# ¿Que tipo de definición de función es esta (python)?

Tags: python

en un ejemplo de código de Pytorch, llaman "función" a un código escrito de la siguiente forma:

```
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225] )])
# ###########################################
img = Image.open("bobby.jpg")
img.show()

img_t = preprocess(img)
```

Yo estaba acostumbrado a que las funciones se empiezan con la palabra clave "def" por esto no entiendo que sucede aquí, muchas gracias!.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No estás definiendo una función, estás llamando un método (función) y le estás pasando parámetros. El resultados de la llamada al método lo asignas a la variable preprocess